# Почему IDE подчёркивает поля

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю, почему компилятор ругается?

Comment: потому что метод называется toStri**n**g()

Comment: @ а должен как ?

Comment: Если навести / нажать на значок с восклицательным знаком (слева от строки), появится окошко с информацией, которая должна помочь Вам, а если нет, то поможет нам понять что же не так.

Comment: у вас он называется toStrig()

Comment: @Sanek Zhitnik добавил

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что скриншоты ужасны.

Comment: Пусть переделает шкриншоты, что закрывать-то?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У вас переменная `b3` имеет примитивный тип, соответственно и метод вызывать некорректно в данном случае.

Можете написать так: `b3 ? "True" : "False"`.

Либо используйте класс `Boolean`.

Либо используйте статический метод `toString` класса `Boolean`:  `Boolean.toString(b3)`

Comment: Можете добавить в ответ применение типа `Boolean` : `Boolean.toString(b3)`. Не помню происходит ли автоматические преобразования в данном случае, но можно попробовать просто в лоб `jTextField.setText(b3)`Хуже точно не станет.

Comment: @Pavel Parshin   'jTextField1.setText (boolean.toStrig(b3));' оно всёравно ругается

Comment: Boolean - это класс, пишется с заглавной буквы. Метод toString пишется через n

Comment: @Pavel Parshin , спасибо

Comment: У вас же Netbeans, у него же рабочий code completion. Чуть ли не с первой буквы предлагает варианты правильного продолжения. Если чего-то не предлагает в плане вызова методов, значит делаете что-то не так. Не мог же он предложить вызов метода на маленьком boolean.